# In JSF, can any method on a backing bean be called to determine whether to render component or not?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Say I have a managed bean called for example MyBean which has a method called

```
public boolean someMethod () {
    if (something) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The method above is not tied to any field in the backing bean. I am trying to use it like the following:

```
<p:commandButton rendered="#{myBean.someMethod() == false}"></p:commandButton>
```

I am getting the following error:  Function ':someMethod' not found

Can I call the method like above or do I always have to have getters/setter tied to a variable?

Comment: This error is not coming from JSF. Upgrade your code editor.

Comment: I am getting the error when running the page from WebSpere 8.5 which has JSF 2.2 libraries.

Comment: @BalusC is correct.  The error is not from JSF. The method call as I have described above works fine.  I had another unrelated issue.